# Is it possible to detect if the selected item is the first in LINQ-to-SQL?

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

I wonder how I can build a query expression which understands the given item being selected is the first or not. Say I'm selecting 10 items from DB:

```
var query = db.Table.Take(10).Select(t => IsFirst ? t.Value1 : t.Value2);
```

There is an indexed variant of Select but that is not supported in LINQ-to-SQL. If it was supported my problems would be solved. Is there any other trick?

I could have used `ROW_NUMBER()` on T-SQL for instance, which LINQ-to-SQL uses but does not give access to.

I know I can `Concat` two queries and use the first expression in the first and so forth but I don't want to manipulate the rest of the query, just the select statement itself because the query is built at multiple places and this is where I want to behave differently on first row. I'll consider other options if that is not possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the indexed overload, but you need to use the LINQ to Objects version:

```
var query = 
    db.Table.Take(10).AsEnumreable()
    .Select((t, index) => index == 0 ? t.Value1 : t.Value2);
```

Comment: That's what I'm using now. I wondered if it would be possible to do it in the expression. I'm accepting this as the answer until a better alternative comes up.

Answer (score 1):

If `Table` have a primary key. You could do this:

```
var result= (
        from t in db.Table.Take(10)
        let first=db.Table.Take(10).Select (ta =>ta.PrimayKey).First()
        select new
        {
            Value=(t.PrimaryKey=first?t.Value1 : t.Value2)
        }
    );
```